# Javascript plus operator not works with ternary if else

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi this is my js code.

```
var a = '<span> and have </span>' + $('#module_product_review_star_1 .pdp-link')[1] ? $('#module_product_review_star_1 .pdp-link')[1].outerHTML : 'not have';
alert(a);
```

I'm using ternary operator to check the item exists in dom. But when the item is not in dom this code is failing.

this works,

```
if($('#module_product_review_star_1 .pdp-link')[1]){
         questiones = '<span> and have </span>' + $('#module_product_review_star_1 .pdp-link')[1].outerHTML;
}
```

But I need to use ternary operator and do it in one line. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What are you expecting `+` operator to do in that expression? As it is, it concatenates `'<span> and have </span>'` and the result form the `$(...)`, hence the condition is always passed, because the operand of the concatenation is evaluated to truthy nevertheless what the second operand contains. Why should this be on a single line? You should not minify the developement code, let a minifier do that for you when publishing the production code.

Comment: Hello Janith, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please describe your expected results and, if available, add any verbatim error messages that you may be getting. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @carlesgg97. I'll do next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` has higher operator precedence (13) than the conditional operator (4), so your code is checking whether `'<span> and have </span>' + $('#module_product_review_star_1 .pdp-link')[1]` is truthy, which it always will be. Surround everything past the `</span>` in parentheses instead:

```
var a = '<span> and have </span>' + (
  $('#module_product_review_star_1 .pdp-link')[1]
    ? $('#module_product_review_star_1 .pdp-link')[1].outerHTML
    : 'not have'
);
```

That said, it would be better to write DRY code and put `$('#module_product_review_star_1 .pdp-link')[1]` into a variable first:

```
var possibleLink = $('#module_product_review_star_1 .pdp-link')[1];
var a = '<span> and have </span>' + (
  possibleLink
    ? possibleLink.outerHTML
    : 'not have'
);
```

Comment: Thanks so so much but unfortunately I'm getting this error `SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical`

Comment: The code in the answer doesn't have a syntax error - either you have a syntax error elsewhere, or you didn't copy the code exactly

Comment: Sorry I removed unwanted spaces.

Comment: Sure, you can squeeze it all onto one line if you like, but that really hurts the code's readability, and code readability is usually the most important thing to strive for when writing code

Comment: I totaly agree but the way I did that was very wrong and just fixed it on both my q and your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Ternary has this pattern:

```
condition ? do if true : do if false;
```

so in your case condition is

```
'<span> and have </span>' + $('#module_product_review_star_1 .pdp-link')[1]
```